# Error test upload file java webflux

Tags: java, fileupload, spring-webflux

Cuando intento ejecutar este test me arroja el siguiente error.

`java.lang.NullPointerException: A la altura de .map(dataBuffer -> { lineas mas abajo....`

Adjunto Test:

```
 @Test
    void testing_1() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        FilePart filePart = BDDMockito.mock(FilePart.class);
        BDDMockito.given(filePart.filename()).willReturn("resources/ejemplo.csv");
        Mockito.when(repo.metodo(any())).thenReturn("Abcd");                
        service.importData(filePart);}
```

Clase service:

```
public Flux<String> importData(FilePart filePart) {
        return filePart.content().map(dataBuffer -> {
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
                    dataBuffer.read(bytes);
                    DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
                    return bytes;})
                .map(t -> {});
}
```

Comment: asegurate de tratar de siempre poner un [mcve]. En este caso con lo que pones no se puede reproducir tu problema.

Comment: El tema es q en la respuesta no me deja poner el codigo....no se si editando el comentario ayude

Comment: en tu prueba unitaria `filePart.content()` no tiene mock, por lo que por defecto regresa null. Infiero que de alli es que te de NPE, lamento no poderte ayudar mas.